# Send Video between servers using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming

i am working in a project using node. My goal is to get a video from one server to the other. I am using udp protocol, so, i just want to know, how i must work with the video and how to do that. I mean, must i convert the video to a string and sent it by the socket udp? I know how to send strings, but i don't know how to apply this using video. Cpuld you help me please?

This is the code i use for the listening server:

```
var PORT = 33333;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server Running on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log(remote.address + ':' + remote.port +' - ' + message);

});

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

Regards

Comment: You need to send bytes.  Videos are no different from other files.  Learn about streams.

Comment: Hi @SLaks, do you have any link or example where i can use as a guide? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ok Guys, i got it. The problem i have now, is the size of the video. How i can slice the byte array and send it to the server? Is this approach the best practice?

Comment: You should pipe a stream from the file to the server.